# Trim returns error 424 object required

Tags: excel, vba, object, trim, required

I'm trying to make function that makes hyperlink from 2 text fields. Here's the code:

```
 Option Explicit
Sub AddLink()

    Dim MyPath
    Dim MyChar
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myString
    Dim numbers
    Dim siteID
    Dim MyWB
    Dim siteAddress
    MyPath = "SomeFilePath\"
    MyChar = "\"

    For i = 2 To 4000 Step 1
        myString = Range("B" & i).Value
        numbers = myString.TrimStart(MyChar)
        siteID = Range("F" & i).Value

        MyWB = "WO_" & numbers & "_" & siteID & ".xls"
        siteAddress = MyPath & MyWB
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("B" & i), siteAddress

    Next i

End Sub
```

So I get error on "numbers = myString.TrimStart(MyChar)" -   error 424 object required.
I'm rly big noob @ vba, could you help me? 
PS I know that I should define the variable type, but when I do this I get again some f... errors that drives me nuts.

Comment: you should provide code form `myString.TrimStart` class\property which I guess it is. Or you possibly did not set myString class object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like vb.net not vba. Trim removes spaces. So vba is `x = trim(str)`. Maybe use `instr` to get position of first backslash thenuse `Left` function.

Comment: Something like `numbers = Left(myString, InStr(1, myString, Chr(92)) - 1)`.

Comment: You are right :) I made it that way and everything works fine :) 10x